# Detect if browser supports FREEZE and RESUME lifecycle events

Tags: javascript, browser

How can I detect if a browser supports the `freeze` and `resume` [lifecycle events](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/page-lifecycle-api/)?

I've looked at the old faithful JS library, Modernizr, and it doesn't seem to support their detection.

They seem so useful, but Safari and Firefox don't currently support these events according to CanIUse.

Is there another way to do it?

```
document.addEventListener('onfreeze', (event) => {
    console.log('Frozen');
});

document.addEventListener('onresume', (event) => {
    console.log('Resumed');
});
```

Comment: `'onfreeze' in document`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for `onxyz` members on the source objects is a time-honored way of detecting event support. And it looks like it applies here: [The specification](https://wicg.github.io/page-lifecycle/spec.html#sec-api) defines `onfreeze` and `onresume` members of `Document`:

> Page Lifecycle involves the following additions:
>
> ```
> partial interface Document {
>     attribute EventHandler onfreeze;
>     attribute EventHandler onresume;
>     readonly attribute boolean wasDiscarded;
> };
> ```

So `if ("onfreeze" in document)` should tell you if the environment supports the `freeze` event (and the same for `resume`, though they're likely to both be supported, or neither).